# why does google cloude ml training job give zero utilization stats for hours?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am running a tensorflow training job like so:

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_eval_validation_`date +%s` --job-dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz --module-name object_detection.model_main --runtime-version 1.9 --scale-tier BASIC_GPU --region us-central1 -- --model_dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train --pipeline_config_path=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/pinches_pipeleine.config --checkpoint_dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train

The job is running for 4 hours (still going) and is repeating the following logs with zero utilization stats as following:

INFO    2019-02-21 18:33:19 -0600   master-replica-0        index, memory.used [MiB], memory.total [MiB], utilization.gpu [%], power.draw [W], power.limit [W] 
INFO    2019-02-21 18:33:19 -0600   master-replica-0        0, 0 MiB, 11441 MiB, 0 %, 27.72 W, 149.00 W 
INFO    2019-02-21 18:38:19 -0600   master-replica-0        index, memory.used [MiB], memory.total [MiB], utilization.gpu [%], power.draw [W], power.limit [W]  
INFO    2019-02-21 18:38:19 -0600   master-replica-0        0, 0 MiB, 11441 MiB, 0 %, 27.72 W, 149.00 W 
INFO    2019-02-21 18:43:19 -0600   master-replica-0        index, memory.used [MiB], memory.total [MiB], utilization.gpu [%], power.draw [W], power.limit [W] 
INFO    2019-02-21 18:43:19 -0600   master-replica-0        0, 0 MiB, 11441 MiB, 0 %, 27.72 W, 149.00 W

What does it mean? Does it mean some kind of error, or its scheduled, but not running?. It definitely ran and did the initia build stuff.

Thanks

Comment: I got the same problem today. 
It is strange because last week this wasn't happening.
Perhaps it is a ML Engine bug, once when running locally on my computer the GPU is being used and the training runs normally.
Which runtime version are you using? I'm currently using 1.12